# rping server crashes in ported kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, infiniband, rdma

I have installed **Soft-RoCE** and the rdma connection between two nodes are ensured successfully using **"rping"** in **Kernel 3.0.0+.**

I need to do the same in the **kernel 4.0.4**. I have copied "**rxe driver** (/driver/infiniband/hw/rxe)" from 3.0.0+ to kernel 4.0.4. and i have applied small patch so that rxe holds good in 4.0.4.

After porting, in 4.0.4,                                                       the **rping server gets crashed** when the client tries to connect with it.
the server seems to be running...I get the crash report on the dmesg.

ibv_devices, ibv_devinfo produces output.

Kindly help me the steps to solve this problem

the following is the crash report

```
root@ls2085aqds:/etc/libibverbs.d# rping -s
------------[ cut here ]------------
WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 810 at kernel/softirq.c:146 __local_bh_enable_ip+0x84/0xc0()
Modules linked in: ib_rxe_net ib_rxe rdma_ucm ib_ucm ib_uverbs ib_umad rdma_cm iw_cm ib_cm ib_sa ib_mad ib_core ib_addr ipv6
CPU: 0 PID: 810 Comm: kworker/0:1 Not tainted 3.16.0-Layerscape2-SDK+g330dd4b #20
Workqueue: ib_cm cm_work_handler [ib_cm]
Call trace:
[<ffffffc000088084>] dump_backtrace+0x0/0x12c
[<ffffffc0000881c0>] show_stack+0x10/0x1c
[<ffffffc000552fa4>] dump_stack+0x74/0xc4
[<ffffffc0000a9b8c>] warn_slowpath_common+0x84/0xac
[<ffffffc0000a9c78>] warn_slowpath_null+0x14/0x20
[<ffffffc0000ae3d0>] __local_bh_enable_ip+0x80/0xc0
[<ffffffc00049fccc>] __dev_queue_xmit+0x1cc/0x408
[<ffffffc00049ff14>] dev_queue_xmit+0xc/0x18
[<ffffffbffc11b620>] send_finish+0x34/0x40 [ib_rxe_net]
[<ffffffbffc11b6b8>] send+0x8c/0xec [ib_rxe_net]
[<ffffffbffc10933c>] $x+0x318/0x334 [ib_rxe]
[<ffffffbffc109be0>] $x+0xa8/0x120 [ib_rxe]
[<ffffffbffc109d54>] rxe_run_task+0x4c/0x90 [ib_rxe]
[<ffffffbffc1093b4>] arbiter_skb_queue+0x5c/0x8c [ib_rxe]
[<ffffffbffc0fffd4>] rxe_requester+0x83c/0xddc [ib_rxe]
[<ffffffbffc109be0>] $x+0xa8/0x120 [ib_rxe]
[<ffffffbffc109d54>] rxe_run_task+0x4c/0x90 [ib_rxe]
[<ffffffbffc104e0c>] rxe_post_send+0x80/0x40c [ib_rxe]
[<ffffffbffc097068>] ib_send_mad+0x288/0x454 [ib_mad]
[<ffffffbffc09759c>] ib_post_send_mad+0x190/0x544 [ib_mad]
[<ffffffbffc0b075c>] ib_send_cm_rej+0xd0/0x194 [ib_cm]
[<ffffffbffc0b19b8>] cm_destroy_id+0x188/0x300 [ib_cm]
[<ffffffbffc0b1e80>] cm_process_work+0x154/0x17c [ib_cm]
[<ffffffbffc0b2600>] cm_req_handler+0x758/0x978 [ib_cm]
[<ffffffbffc0b28ec>] cm_work_handler+0xcc/0x1584 [ib_cm]
[<ffffffc0000c0918>] process_one_work+0x114/0x354
[<ffffffc0000c12f8>] worker_thread+0x13c/0x500
[<ffffffc0000c7034>] kthread+0xd0/0xe8
---[ end trace be7a1b95934c8f03 ]---
```

Comment: benchmark tool "ib_read_bw" is running good in the ported kernel